# No puedo hacer el 'import' de un ReciclerView

Tags: android, android-studio, xml, kotlin, android-recyclerview

al momento de intentar hacer el import no me lo reconoce, ¿alguien sabe el porque? adjunto las imágenes.

Acá ya lo implemente en las dependencias.
[image: dependencias]

y en esta parte es donde estoy tratando hacer el import del ReciclerView pero no me da la opción 'Import'

[image: ReciclewView]

Al darle en la bombilla roja me aparece "crear clase, crear objeto, crear interfaz" pero no importarlo que es lo que me interesa. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Construye el proyecto y revisa si hay otro error, agregalo a tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Debes agregar la dependencia:

```
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
```

para que en tus clases puedas usar el import y la clase `RecyclerView` :

```
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
```

Si no estas pudiendo usar esta clase, esto indica que no esta construido tu proyecto, puedes hacer `Build` -> `Rebuild Project`, si esto no funciona, indica que no se puede construir tu proyecto pero es por otra causa.